# What is the foundational process of generating diverse coloured lines?

Tags: color, drawing

[image]

How are lines like these drawn? The drawing is ofcourse drawn intentionally, but how is the colour assigned here? It's not random but clustered and clustered so well, also what is the choices of colours that make it look the way it does?

Answer (score 2):

Make a Black color fill layer on top of a multicolored image and draw over the mask using different brushes.

[image]

[image]